# Unable to load DLL "x.dll" build warning, but it actually loads fine when I run

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, dllimport

I'm making a forms app in C#. I've built a custom control which makes a couple of calls to a c++ DLL I've had to put together so I can re-use some old code. When I run, it works perfectly. However, I get a build warning that says:

> Unabled to load DLL 'x.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

When I open the forms in the VS designer that use that custom control, it will throw an exception and say it can't find the DLL, but if I hit "Ignore and Continue" then it seems to be fine.

Comment: Just curious, how do you know it runs, when you can not build it in the first place?

Comment: Getting a build warning is hard to explain.  Certainly errors in the designer, you'll really need to fix those since they have a nasty habit of making stuff to disappear.  Code in your control runs at design time as well.  Constructor, Load event, Paint event, etc.  You'll need to use the DesignMode property to prevent code in the DLL from getting called at design time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is because the search path for dlls in VS design view is not the same than during runtime. During runtime, VS has an explicit path set for your application which include for example the /Debug or /Release folder, which is not in the global path.

So VS can't find it, but runtime can. What you could do is to add your dll path to the global windows path or find how to tweak VS search path